# fish shell. How to check if a variable is set/empty?

Tags: shell, fish

How can I do something like

```
set variable (some_command_that_may_return_a_string)
if [ variable is set ]
    do_something
```

and inversely how do I check if the variable is empty?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

- `set -q var` (note the missing "$" - this uses the variable *name*) can be used to check if a variable has been set.
- `set -q var[1]` can be used to check whether the first element of a variable has been assigned (i.e. whether it is non-empty as a list).
- `test -n "$var"` [fn0] (or `[ -n "$var" ]`) can be used to check whether a variable expands to a non-empty string (and `test -z` is the inverse - true if it is empty).

These will be true/false in slightly different circumstances.

When no `set var` has been performed at all (and it has not been inherited from the parent process), `set -q var`, `set -q var[1]` and `test -n "$var"` will be false, `test -z "$var"` will be true.

When something like `set var` has been done (without any additional arguments), `set -q var` will be true, `set -q var[1]` will be false.

When something like `set var ""` has been done, both `set` versions will be true.

When something like `set var "somestring"` (or even `set var "" ""` [fn1]) has been done, the `set`s will be true and `test -z "$var"` will be false.

---

[fn0]: You *never* want to use `test` (or `[`) without quoting the variable. One particularly egregious example is that `test -n $var` will return true both if the variable contains something and if it is list-empty/unset (no `set` at all or `set var` without arguments). This is because fish's `test` is one of the few parts that follow POSIX, and that demands that `test` with any one argument be true. Also it does not handle lists properly - `test -n $var` will have weird results if var has more than one element.

[fn1]: This is because a list will be expanded as a string by joining the elements with spaces, so the list consisting of two empty strings will expand to " " - one space. Since that isn't empty, `test -z` returns false.

Comment: How does this go into an if statement?

Comment: Like all things in shellscript, `if` and then the thing. So `if set -q var[1]`, `if test -n "$var"` and so on. `if` doesn't take a condition but a command to call, and uses its exit status.

Comment: I arrived here to learn that, in fish, we need to quote our variables in `test` and `[ ]` expressions. Thank you for this tidbit, which cured my errors.

Answer (score 16):

@faho provided an awesome answer but I thought it would be easier if there's a code example.

```
function if-test-no-arg
  set var

  if set -q var
    # true
  end

  if set -q var[1]
    # false
  end

  # Always put quotation marks
  if test -n "$var"
    # false
  end

  if test -z "$var"
    # true
  end
end

function if-test-empty-arg
  set var ""

  if set -q var
    # true
  end

  if set -q var[1]
    # true
  end

  if test -n "$var"
    # false
  end

  if test -z "$var"
    # true
  end
end

function if-test-valid-arg
  set var "hello"

  if set -q var
    # true
  end

  if set -q var[1]
    # true
  end

  if test -n "$var"
    # true
  end

  if test -z "$var"
    # false
  end
end

function if-test-no-set
  if set -q var
    # false
  end

  if set -q var[1]
    # false
  end

  if test -n "$var"
    # false
  end

  if test -z "$var"
    # true
  end
end
```

Answer (score 6):

The modern version of fish shell (3.5.1) has `string` commands.

- `string length --quiet $var` checks that the variable is not empty
- `not string length --quiet $var` checks that the variable is empty

Comment: Please provide an example that uses this check in an if statement.

Comment: @zingi example below
```
    if not string length --quiet $ssh_private_key_path
        printf '%s: Please provide the --ssh-private-key-path value\n' $basename
        return 1
    end
```

Comment: [example on pastebin](https://pastebin.com/ddcsQmph)

Comment: @zingi `if` isn't special; all commands return an exit code, and `if` just continues if its argument is equal to 0. Even `[ -n "$var" ]` is a command, an alias for `test`, and returns nonzero if its argument is false. `string length --quiet $var` returns 0 iff `var` is nonempty, which implies its interaction with `if` (and with `&&` and `||` and all other control flow).