# How to define a function that either takes arguments or doesnt?

Tags: fish

I am using Fish shell....
Basically, to do something like this:

```
if (first argument == --r) {
  do something
} else {
  Do something
  if (first argument == --n) {
    do more 
  }
}
```

To achieve the first if statement I tried:

```
 if test (count $argv) -eq 1 -a $argv[1] = '--r'
```

But that gives a message:
test: Missing argument at index 6

Comment: Thanks for the note.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions in [**Fish**](https://fishshell.com) don't require their parameters to be specified when you define the function.  Any arguments sent to the function by the user are automatically stored in an array called `argv`.  In order to determine whether arguments were sent, you can either count the number of elements in the array, or determine the length of the array as a string.  I do the latter:

```
    function my_func
        if [ -z "$argv" ]; # No arguments
            echo "No arguments supplied"
            return
        else # At least one argument
            if [ "$argv[1]" = "--r" ];
                echo "Excellent!"
                return
            end
        end
    end
```

If you prefer to use `count`, then it will look more like this:

```
    function my_func
        if [ (count $argv) -eq 1 -a "$argv[1]" = "--r" ];
            # Exactly one argument with specified value "--r"
            echo "Excellent!"
            return
        else # May have arguments, but none equal to "--r"
            echo "Give me the right arguments"
            return
        end
    end
```

Your use of `set -q argv[1]` is also a good option.  But when you're checking for string equality, don't forget to surround your variable in quotes, like this: `test "$argv[1]" = "--r"`.

Here's another method, using the `switch...case` conditional test:

```
    function my_func
        # No arguments
        if [ -z "$argv" ]; and return

        # At least one argument
        switch $argv[1];
            case --r;
                # do some stuff
                return
            case "*";
                # Any other arguments passed
                return
            end
        end
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
if set -q argv[1] ;and test $argv[1] = "--r"
```

Comment: FWIW, That is an error prone, and unusual, way to write that test. If you can't use the `argparse` command introduced in fish 2.7.0 (by me) the better way to do this is with this pattern:

    if set -q argv[1]
        if test $argv[1] = "--r"
            do something
        else if test $argv[1] = "--n"
            do something
        else
            error
        end
    else
        do something else with zero args
    end

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the error you get when executing this:

```
if test (count $argv) -eq 1 -a $argv[1] = '--r'
```

That happens because fish first expands `$argv[1]` then executes `test`. If argv has no values then that statement turns into

```
if test 0 -eq 1 -a  = '--r'
```

Which isn't valid syntax for the `test` command. It doesn't matter that the first sub-expression evaluates to false since `test` parses the entire expression before evaluating it.

Rather than doing `test (count $argv) -eq 1` just do `set -q argv[1]` to test if argv has at least one argument. Note the lack of a dollar-sign.

If you're using fish 2.7.0 or newer I recommend the new `argparse` builtin for handling arguments. Several of the standard functions that ship with fish use it so you can look at them, as well as `man argparse`, for examples of how to use it. Using `argparse` is almost always safer, less likely to result in bugs due to sloppy argument parsing using hand written fish script, and will provide argument parsing semantics identical to most commands including all the fish builtins. Including correctly handling short and long flags.

Answer (score -1):

well if the argument is optional then you can do this by:

```
//check if variable exists
if (typeof variable === 'undefined'){
}
else{
if(typeof variable){}
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ali, Could you please put in in fish shell syntax? I am new to fish and not sure how this gets translated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47743015/fish-shell-how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-set-empty

Comment: check that link out... this dude gave a full on answer to your question... best of luck :)

Comment: This did not work:     if test -q $argv[1] -a $argv[1] = '--r'